# Intersection of reciprocal and logarithmic bound on sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: logarithms, binomial-coefficients

**Question:** Let $0<s<n$. Assuming that $n$ is fixed, can the following equation be solved for $s$?
$$
n\log_2\left(\frac{n}{n-s}\right) + s\log_2\left(\frac{n-s}{s}\right) = \frac{n}{s}
$$

If there is no analytic solution, is there a technique for approximating $s$?

**Background:** For my research, I am working on inferring a subexponential ($2^{o(n)}$) bound on the number of binary words of length $n$ with at most $s$ ones. The starting point for was thus the sum of the first $s$ binomial coefficients, which, after taking the logarithm of both sides, relaxing the inequality and using Stirling's approximation, eventually leads to an inequality that is bounded by the equation above. Originally, I was looking into known tail bounds on the binomial distribution, but as far as I know these only permit an exponential solution. I got a similar result playing around with the Chernoff bound.

**What I have tried so far:** For virtually all $n$ and $s$, there should be exactly two intersections, one close to $\log_2(n)$, and the other close to $n$. Using the properties of the logarithm,
the equation can be rearranged into, e.g.,
$$
n\log_2(n) - (n-s)\log_2(n-s) - s\log_2(s) = \frac{n}{s}
$$
but I don't see how I would get $s$ (or $n$) out of all logarithms. Did I maybe overlook something simple? When I use Ash's bounds on the sum of binomial distributions, I get a very similar result to the equation above.

Comment: Here is your plot of $k(n)$   https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ContourPlot%5BLog%5B2%5D%2Fn+%2B+k*%28Log%5B1+-+k%5D+-+k*Log%5B1+-+k%5D+%2B+k*Log%5Bk%5D%29%3D%3D0%2C%7Bn%2C2%2C100%7D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C1%7D%5D

Comment: Obviously, the link is broken but you can type it again. Do you care or not about $k_2$ ?

Comment: I am fine with $k_1$, thank you very much

Comment: $k_2$ approximate value found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I shall use natural logarithms*
$$n\log\left(\frac{n}{n-s}\right) + s\log\left(\frac{n-s}{s}\right) = \frac{n}{s}\log(2)$$ Since $n$ is fixed, let $s= kn$ $(0 < k <1)$ and solve for $n$; this gives
$$n=-\frac{\log (2)}{k ((1-k) \log (1-k)+k \log (k))}$$
As you wrote, for a given value of $n$, there are two solutions in $k$  if $n>1.621$.

So, we need to find the zeros of function
$$F(k)=k ((1-k) \log (1-k)+k \log (k))+\frac{\log (2)}n$$ Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n &   k_1 & k_2 \\
 2 &  0.500000 &  0.861456 \\
 3 &  0.355146 &  0.932224 \\
 4 &  0.288448 &  0.955720 \\
 5 &  0.247662 &  0.967513 \\
 6 &  0.219509 &  0.974553 \\
 7 &  0.198636 &  0.979203 \\
 8 &  0.182401 &  0.982489 \\
  9 &  0.169332 &  0.984925 \\
 10 &  0.158532 &  0.986799 \\
 15 &  0.123566 &  0.992003 \\
 20 &  0.103899 &  0.994355 \\
 25 &  0.090971 &  0.995677 \\
 30 &  0.081683 &  0.996518 \\
 35 &  0.074615 &  0.997096 \\
 40 &  0.069015 &  0.997517 \\
 45 &  0.064443 &  0.997836 \\
 50 &  0.060622 &  0.998086 \\
 60 &  0.054561 &  0.998451 \\
 70 &  0.049932 &  0.998703 \\
 80 &  0.046252 &  0.998888 \\
  90 &  0.043241 &  0.999029 \\
 100 &  0.040720 &  0.999139
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, trying to make approximations :

For small values of $k$, we have
$$\frac{\log (2)}{n}+k^2 (\log (k)-1)+\dots=0 \quad \implies \quad \color{red}{k_1 \simeq  \sqrt {-\frac{2 \log (2)}{n \,W_{-1}\left(-\frac{2 \log (2)}{e^2 n}\right)}  }}$$ which, for $n=10$ gives $k_1=0.155680$ (exact value $k_1=0.158532$) and for $n=100$ gives $k_1=0.040606$ (exact value $k_1=0.040720$).

This gives a good starting point for Newton method with
$$F'(k)=(1-2 k) \log (1-k)+2 k \log (k)$$ For example, for $n=5$, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 m & k_m \\
 0 & 0.23873087 \\
 1 & 0.24770888 \\
 2 & 0.24766217
\end{array}
\right)$$

So, for $k_1$, with a single iteration of Newton method, we almost have the analytical solution of the problem.

For the second root, the expansion around $k=1$ gives
$$\frac{\log (2)}{n}+(1-k) (\log (1-k)-1)+\dots=0\implies \color{red}{k_2\simeq 1+\frac{\log (2)}{n W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{e n}\right)}}$$
which, for $n=10$ gives $k_2=0.987033$ (exact value $k_2=0.986799$) and for $n=100$ gives $k_2=0.999140$ (exact value $k_2=0.999139$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since $0<s<n$ and $0<k<1$, shouldn't it be $s=kn$?

Comment: @mto_19. Sure ! This is a typo. Sorry for that. I shall finish tomorrow morning (ft the solution in $k=f(n)$. Dinner time here. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you for the additions. I would upvote your answer if I had sufficient reputation. Could you maybe briefly elaborate how you interpret the $\sim$ in Equation 1? I would read it as $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{k_1}{\sqrt{-\frac{2\log(2)}{nW_{-1}\left(-\frac{2\log(2)}{e^2n}\right)}}}=1$, but I am not sure if this was the intended usage

Comment: @mto_19.  Typo fixed